# checkout_agreement_store doesn't exist

Tags: magento2, bug, magento-upgrade, prefix, billing-agreements

Any idea?

Preconditions

- Starting from Magento CE 2.2.5
- Upgrade from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6

Steps to reproduce

- Starting from Magento CE 2.2.5
- Created a terms and conditions (Store-->Terms and conditions)
- Upgrade from 2.2.5 to 2.2.6
- The Terms and conditions created are not visible in admin (Store-->Terms and conditions)

Expected result

- I can edit the old terms and conditions
- I can insert a new terms and conditions

Actual result

- Old terms and conditions are not visible
- In production mode I can add a new terms and conditions but is not visible in admiview
- In developer mode there is an exception:

> 2 exception(s): Exception #0 (Zend_Db_Statement_Exception):
>   SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table
>   'XXXXXX.checkout_agreement_store' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT
>   agreement_store.* FROM checkout_agreement_store AS agreement_store
>   WHERE (agreement_store.agreement_id IN ('1')) Exception #1
>   (PDOException): SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146
>   Table 'XXXXXX.checkout_agreement_store' doesn't exist

The table exists in DB; note that in sql there isn't the prefix to table.

Comment: Are you able to query agreement table from other cliet (cli or workbench or similar)?

Answer (score 1):

I find the issue and the solution In

> /vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement/Grid/Collection.php

There is an issue:

```
private function getStoresForAgreements()
{
    $agreementId = $this->getColumnValues('agreement_id');

    if (!empty($agreementId)) {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
            ['agreement_store' => 'checkout_agreement_store']
        )->where(
            'agreement_store.agreement_id IN (?)',
            $agreementId
        );

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    }

    return [];
}
```

**Change with below**

```
private function getStoresForAgreements()
{
    $agreementId = $this->getColumnValues('agreement_id');

    if (!empty($agreementId)) {
        $select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
            [$this->getTable('agreement_store') => $this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store')]
        )->where(
            $this->getTable('agreement_store').'.agreement_id IN (?)',
            $agreementId
        );

        return $this->getConnection()->fetchAll($select);
    }

    return [];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In `/vendor/magento/module-checkout-agreements/Model/ResourceModel/Agreement/Grid/Collection.php` it is enough to change:

```
$select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
    ['agreement_store' => 'checkout_agreement_store']
```

To:

```
$select = $this->getConnection()->select()->from(
    ['agreement_store' => $this->getTable('checkout_agreement_store')]
```

---

- PR-2.2: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18866
- PR-2.3: https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/18412